# `su` and `sudo bash` give a root prompt that won't execute any command

Tags: linux, bash, centos, root

This is happening on a CentOS 6.7 server, that I can ssh to as root or as my ordinary user.

Opening an ssh session as an ordinary user and switching to root within the session gets the expected prompt, but any command goes back to the previous state:

```
ordinary@server [~]# su
Password: 
root@server [/home/ordinary]# ls
ordinary@server [~]# sudo bash
[sudo] password for root: 
root@server [/home/ordinary]# ls
ordinary@server [~]#
```

`su -` does the same thing. Adding `set -xv` to the end of `/root/.bashrc` generates some additional output:

```
ordinary@server [~]# su
Password: 
history -a
__rvm_date "+%s.%N" 2>/dev/null) ${BASH_SOURCE##${rvm_path:-}} : ${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}()}  ${LINENO} > 
__rvm_date "+%s.%N" 2>/dev/null
++   :   0 > history -a
root@server [/home/ordinary]# ls
ordinary@server [~]# su -
Password: 

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
+ PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/sbin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin

export PATH
+ export PATH
history -a
++ history -a
root@server [~]# ls
ordinary@server [~]# sudo bash
[sudo] password for root: 
history -a
++ history -a
root@server [/home/ordinary]# ls
ordinary@server [~]#
```

What is going on here? It looks like authentication is working, bash is giving its prompt and waiting for a command, but exiting before running the command it gets. Is there anywhere I can look for an error message?

---

Here are the startup files for root:

.profile does not exist

.bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

.bashrc:

```
#################################################
# interactive failsafes and general aliasing
#################################################
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias grep='grep --color'

############################
# Source global definitions
############################
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

############################
# Important history hacks
############################
#how many lines to keep in the history FILE
export HISTFILESIZE=500000
#how many lines to keep in memory for this SESSION.
export HISTSIZE=200000
#how to make it oh so very pretty.
HISTTIMEFORMAT="(%m/%d/%y) %T "
export HISTTIMEFORMAT
#append the history for all terminals
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'

###########################
# give some terminal <3
###########################
#set check window resize
shopt -s checkwinsize 

#######################
# vim defaults
#######################
alias vi=vim
export EDITOR=vim

# EOF

#set -xv
```

---

`sudo bash --norc` does the same thing.  Here's the log of that from `sudo strace -o bash--norc.strace bash --norc`:

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "--norc"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x28d0000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8d4ce2000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=54952, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 54952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb8d4cd4000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\310\0k<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=134792, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c6b000000, 2228832, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c6b000000
mprotect(0x3c6b01d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c6b21c000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c000) = 0x3c6b21c000
mmap(0x3c6b220000, 608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c6b220000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)     = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\200d<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=22536, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x3c64800000, 2109696, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c64800000
mprotect(0x3c64802000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c64a02000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x3c64a02000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\356Ad<\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8d4cd3000
mmap(0x3c64400000, 3750152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x3c64400000
mprotect(0x3c6458a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x3c6478a000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18a000) = 0x3c6478a000
mmap(0x3c6478f000, 18696, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3c6478f000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8d4cd2000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8d4cd1000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb8d4cd2700) = 0
mprotect(0x3c64a02000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c6478a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x3c6421f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fb8d4cd4000, 54952)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x28d0000
brk(0x28f1000)                          = 0x28f1000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99154480, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 99154480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb8cee41000
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8d4ce1000
read(3, "MemTotal:        8048372 kB\nMemF"..., 1024) = 1024
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fb8d4ce1000, 4096)            = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x452410, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="server", ...}) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = 0
sendto(3, "\2\0\0\0\v\0\0\0\7\0\0\0passwd\0", 19, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 19
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"passwd\0", 7}, {"\270O\3\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=24, {cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, {4}}, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 15
mmap(NULL, 217016, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x7fb8cee0c000
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getcwd("/home/ordinary", 4096)       = 18
getpid()                                = 24450
open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26060, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26060, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fb8cee05000
close(3)                                = 0
getppid()                               = 24447
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/sbin/bash", 0x7fff1c54f990)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=941768, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
getpgrp()                               = 24446
dup(2)                                  = 3
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFD)                     = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [24446])          = 0
setpgid(0, 24450)                       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(255, SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_SELECT or TIOCSPGRP, [24450]) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(255, TIOCGPGRP, [24450])          = 0
fcntl(255, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x43f5a0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(255, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=62714, rlim_max=62714}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
open("/root/.bash_history", O_RDONLY)   = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=49948, ...}) = 0
read(3, "screen -S ded_setup\nexit\n#137414"..., 49948) = 49948
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/root/.bash_history", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=49948, ...}) = 0
open("/root/.bash_history", O_RDONLY)   = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=49948, ...}) = 0
read(3, "screen -S ded_setup\nexit\n#137414"..., 49948) = 49948
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0x2912000)                          = 0x2912000
ioctl(255, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/root/.terminfo", 0x7fff1c54dae0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/etc/terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/share/terminfo", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce", R_OK) = 0
open("/usr/share/terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\32\0017\0+\0\20\0i\1\325\2screen-256color-bce|"..., 4097) = 1840
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_STATUS or TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/inputrc", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=942, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/inputrc", O_RDONLY)          = 3
read(3, "# do not bell on tab-completion\n"..., 942) = 942
close(3)                                = 0
brk(0x2933000)                          = 0x2933000
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(255, SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_SELECT or TIOCSPGRP, [24450]) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_STATUS or TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=51, ws_col=209, ws_xpixel=1254, ws_ypixel=663}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B9600 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT QUIT ALRM TERM TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x4959a0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452410, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 1), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8cee04000
write(2, "bash-4.1# ", 10)              = 10
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "l", 1)                         = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
write(2, "l", 1)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "s", 1)                         = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
write(2, "s", 1)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_GINFO or TCSETSW, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x495aa0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x452410, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x4959a0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, 9)         = 3
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(12)={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, msg_iov(2)=[{"\23\0\0\0d\4\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16}, {"ls\0", 3}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 19
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x452880, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B9600 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/1", 4095) = 10
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x3c64524720, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, 8) = 0
alarm(10)                               = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_RDLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
read(3, "\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\1\0\0\0003\0\0\0~\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\221\37\0\0tty3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\225\37\0\0tty5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\217\37\0\0tty2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\223\37\0\0tty4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\215\37\0\0tty1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\6\0\0\0\227\37\0\0tty6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\7\0\0\0\247]\0\0pts/0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0%,\0\0pts/1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0J<\0\0pts/2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0002V\0\0pts/3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\275\t\0\0pts/5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\275\f\0\0pts/7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\263\22\0\0pts/9\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0?M\0\0pts/10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\244t\0\0pts/11\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\352\n\0\0pts/13\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\23\"\0\0pts/15\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\213>\0\0pts/17\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0x)\0\0pts/6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\377G\0\0pts/8\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\3051\0\0pts/12\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\352\f\0\0pts/14\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\311,\0\0pts/16\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0yA\0\0pts/19\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0A\10\0\0pts/5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\323\36\0\0pts/4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\rY\0\0pts/3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0ll\0\0pts/1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0=&\0\0pts/4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0}*\0\0pts/6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "\10\0\0\0\317\25\0\0pts/8\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 384) = 384
read(3, "", 384)                        = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=0}) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 10
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x4525f0, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], SA_RESTORER, 0x3c644326a0}, NULL, 8) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/dev/log"}, 110) = 0
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8cee03000
read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 3519
lseek(5, -2252, SEEK_CUR)               = 1267
read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2252
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fb8cee03000, 4096)            = 0
sendto(4, "<151>Nov 17 10:30:55 bash: No UT"..., 63, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 63
close(4)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I don't know enough to spot the problem in this log, but I do see where it tries to write to `/dev/log` a message that starts with "bash: No UT".  I guessed that had something to do with utmp, and tried clearing `/var/run/utmp`, but that had no effect.

Comment: What about any other shell? (Maybe `busybox ash`, if you have no other shell installed)

Comment: We'd need to see all of root's bash startup files: ~/.profile, ~/bash_profile, ~/.bashrc and any file sourced by any of those.

Comment: Can you echo your PS1 setting for the ordinary user?

Comment: `sudo busybox ash` seems to work - I can run `ls` in ash.  But running `bash` in ash exits in the same way.

Comment: Added startup file contents to question.  PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"

Comment: For ordinary user, PS1="\u@\h [\w]#"

Comment: Immediately after `sudo bash` returns, what does `echo $?` print? Does `sudo bash --norc` work? If you can't figure out the problem, break out the big guns: `sudo strace -o bash.strace bash`, and post the trace. (Do not run `strace sudo …`, as that would log your password if sudo prompts for it. `sudo strace …` is fine.)

Comment: `echo $?` prints 0.  `sudo bash --norc` exits in the same way.

Comment: I don't see any obvious error in the generated `bash.strace`, but I doubt I know what to look for.  It seems to write "ls\0" (the command I entered) to an unconnected socket. Near the end it appears to write a message beginning with "bash: No UT" to /dev/log, but that message is not written to any file in /var/log.  Should I add the trace of `bash --norc` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo -s`.
This should fix it.

Comment: I tried `sudo -s` and it worked... so I tried `su` and `sudo bash` again and they both worked as well.  I can't tell if the problem spontaneously resolved itself or if `sudo -s` does something more than just `sudo $SHELL`.  What does `sudo -s` do that would fix the problem?

Comment: It's just another variant of su, but I don't know why this fixes it